# mysql/pandas dataframe update column based on time sequence

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas

Imagine a table with 3 columns: orderid, entry and time.
For each orderid there would be 2 entries, when the order is opened and when it is closed.
The entry is 0 by default, I wish to update the entry to set the one with later time be 1.
If the orderid only appears once, it means this order is still open thus the entry should remain 0.

[image]

Is there anyway I can do it using an update query?

Edit:

I found it extremely inefficient to run the update query in MYSQL given that the table is quite big with new data constantly inserted.

Since I am using Python pandas to generate DataFrame before inserting it to the table, is there any way I can do it within the DataFrame?

so

```py
order = [(11111,0,'2020-09-18 01:21:12'),(11111,0,'2020-09-18 01:50:12')]
df = pandas.DataFrame(order,columns = ['orderid','entry','time'])
```

How do I handle this df to have the entry with later time become 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a self join:

```
update orders o1 inner join orders o2
on o1.orderid = o2.orderid and o1.time > o2.time
set o1.entry = 1
```

Comment: I wish to include where clause in the update query so that rows are already updated wouldn't be checked again in the future as this table will be constantly updated and only orderid that appears more than once will be checked. I can add a where however won't be able to group by it?
`where count(o1.orderid) > 1 and sum(o1.entry = 0)`

Comment: You can add at the end: `WHERE o1.entry = 0` or `WHERE o1.entry <> 1`, but MySql does not update if the new value is the same as the current.

Comment: sorry mate didn't realize I unaccepted the answer, should be a wrong click